# mount partition with installed ubuntu from another ubuntu installation

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, partitioning

i have fresh installation of ubuntu on SSD. now i need to transfer some files from my old ubuntu installation (located on HDD) i'm trying to mount it but receiving error about corrupted files.

but i can boot with it without problem (old ubuntu from hdd) i also dont want to kill the old ubuntu (in case of some repairs) so i can later boot with it as a backup second system

[image]

the question is how to fix this problem and access that partition without breaking something, so after this fix i could boot from hdd with the installed linux on it

another screen from gparted
[image: https://i.imgur.com/043BRa1.png]
"mount" possibility disabled probably because of that warning message from the screenshot

Comment: Was there a question you forgot to ask?

Comment: the question is how to fix this problem and access that partition without breaking something, so after this fix i could boot from hdd with the installed linux on it

Comment: Step 1: Look up how to run 'fsck' (FileSystem ChecK) on /dev/sdc8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

followed this guide
https://linuxexpresso.wordpress.com/2010/03/31/repair-a-broken-ext4-superblock-in-ubuntu/

the point about 
`sudo fsck.ext4 -v /dev/XXX`

fixed the problem after the huge amount of approved fixes

thanks to all.